# Hibernation Issues

Tags: suspend, hibernate

This is my first post here. I recently took back up my attempt to get hibernation to work on my laptop. I followed the Ubuntu official documentation and several posts on here but none of them fixed it. I do have enough swap memory I even created more. I am about to update to 17.04 from 16.04 to see if that will help solve the problem.

*Edit it doesn't hibernate in windows.

Would trying a different Distro fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a reason why hibernation isn't available by default: risk of data loss and no practical advantage in any modern hardware. Suspension, which is different from hibernation, is probably what you want, you know, close the lid and it sustends, open the lid and it wakes up, fast and safe. Hibernating takes as much or more time then shutting down and powering on again, plus it doesn't respond to to open lid signal.

Comment: @user589808, "no practical advantage in any modern hardware..." That's a very extreme and subjective statement. So you can't think of any use case where hibernate is more appropriate than suspend? How about when you want to maintain state with zero battery discharge? Personally, I use both hibernate and suspend (hybrid-sleep), depending on context.